# Is there explanation for this threading code?

Tags: asynchronous, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

So have come across some code very similar to this. I am just wondering if someone can explain this to me.

See how it uses RX scheduler then Parallel.For and inside that a new TaskFactory.StartNew

```
    IDisposable subscription = someObservable.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .Subscribe(o =>
       {
           Parallel.ForEach(xxxs,
               x =>
               {
                   var theKey = x.Key;
                   if (!theTasks.ContainsKey(theKey) ||
                       theTasks.ContainsKey(theKey) && theTasks[theKey].IsCompleted)
                   {
                       theTasks[theKey] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                           () =>
                           {
                               .....
                               }
                               catch (CommunicationObjectAbortedException ex)
                               {
                               ....
                               }
                               catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
                               {
                               ....
                               }
                               catch (Exception e)
                               {
                               ....
                               }
                           });
                   }
               });
       },
       ex =>
       {
          ....
       },
       () =>
       {
          ....
       });
    }
```

I know what all these things do individually, but am not really sure what the combined threading effect here is. Can anyone hazzard a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah yes, the concurrency [Turducken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turducken).

`ThreadPoolScheduler` schedules work on the *thread pool* which is distinct from the *task pool*. `ThreadPoolScheduler` was meant to be used to on platforms where a task pool was not available - prefer `TaskPoolScheduler` when possible.

It feels like the writer was trying to save up the task pool for only the task at hand (pardon the pun), by using the thread pool.

`Parallel.ForEach` blocks until the loop has been completed.  So while it was running on the thread pool, when a new item is emitted, do the next `ForEach` on a borrowed thread from the thread pool.

As for the inner bit, the writer wants one `Task` to be run per unique key, if isn't already running.